# Intellisense namespace discovery in Visual Studio not working after moving files to another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense

I started with a single ASP.Net MVC project named Yogabandy2017 that had a folder called viewmodels. I stored all the viewmodels in it.

[image]

I moved all the files from that folder to another project called Yogabandy2017.Models where I stored all my models and I created a folder in it called Viewmodels where I put all the viewmodels, I also changed the namespacing in each of the viewmodels to match.

[image]

Then I did a large copy and 'replace all' in each view so that each view can now point to the correct folder like this

[image]

from this

[image]

to this, where I added the .Models to make the path correct

[image]

But intellisense still hasn't changed and picked up the correct path. I've tried to clean the solution, rebiuild it a couple of times. and still the path isn't connecting correctly. I still have the red underline and an exception being thrown when traversing the page saying it can't find the path.

Is there any way to get these paths to reset without going to each file and rewritting them manually? I have a few hundred and going through each one by one to make the change will take forever.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: whats the exception ??

Comment: that it can't find the path!

Comment: Did you add `Yogabandy2017.Models` project as a reference to the `Yogabandy2017` project? If not then add the reference and rebuild.

Comment: yes of course!!!

Comment: share a root namespace of a new project, a namespace of any own file from this project, a namespace of the moved ViewModel(s) if have changed them

Comment: It appears that your classes in Yogabandy2017.ViewModels cannot get compiled. That is even before VS tries to compile your Views. Check there first. Intellisence is looking for the compiled classes and they are not there.

Answer (score -1):

Check your cases...
Yoga**B**andy2017 
vs.
Yoga**b**andy2017